# wxWidgets timer doesn't start?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets, sleep

This wxWidgets code (simulating a portable *sleep*), does not work.

```
MyClass::MyClass(){
m_timer = std::make_shared<wxTimer>(this, ID_TIMER);
}

void MyClass::WaitOneSecond()
{
  m_timer->StartOnce(1000);
  while (m_timer->GetInterval() < 1000);
}
```

When stepping with Visual Studio over a WaitOneSecond call, no delay appears.
**Why ?...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `wxwTimer` works with the `WxWidget`'s event loop.

That means it will notify you after the delay as expired, but you must give control back.

As explained in the documentation:

> There are three different ways to use this class:
>
> - You may derive a new class from wxTimer and override the wxTimer::Notify member to perform the required action.
> - You may redirect the notifications to any wxEvtHandler derived object by using the non-default constructor or wxTimer::SetOwner. Then
>     use the EVT_TIMER macro to connect it to the event handler which will
>     receive wxTimerEvent notifications.
> - You may use a derived class and the EVT_TIMER macro to connect it to an event handler defined in the derived class. If the default
>     constructor is used, the timer object will be its own owner object,
>     since it is derived from wxEvtHandler.

Answer (score 2):

wxWidgets has a sleep function  [wxMilliSleep](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__time.html#ga66778879349f76fd833902d3767006fa)

C++11 has a per thread sleep: [std::this_thread::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)